# How get State-Space representation after c2d(sys,ts)?

Tags: matlab, controls, system, state-space

I don't understand how get the matrix A,B,C,D after discretizing, for example:

```
sys = ss(A,B,C,D);

% if Ts>0 then sample the model with a zero-order hold (piecewise constant) input, otherwise return a continuous-time model
if Ts>0
     sysd = c2d(sys,Ts);
%     Return discrete-time SS model matrices
     
end
```

How can i get A, B, C, D from sysd?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you try `sysd.A`?

Answer (score 0):

The function that you are looking for is [`ssdata`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lti.ssdata.html).

```
[Ad, Bd, Cd, Dd] = ssdata(sysd);
```

Alternatively, you can access them with dot indexing. i.e.

```
sysd.A
sysd.B
sysd.C
sysd.D
```